# Merging multiple canvas in a single DIV together - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I have a method that creates different layers of `canvas` within single `divs` based on data.  Sometimes a div will contain more than one `canvas` within it. These `canvas` contain an image which is usually a `PNG`.  What I am trying to do is take every `canvas` within a single div and render as one single `canvas` so that every `div` would contain combined `canvases` if they had more than one within it.

Here is what I am doing:

```
// Loop through each div that contains canvas and combine them
            $(".ifp_container_printing").each(function(index, element) {
                var primaryCanvas = $(this).closest('canvas');
                var thisOne = $(this);
                thisOne.find('canvas').each(function(index, element) {//<!-- grab the canvas for this parent div
                    var childCanvas = $(this).get();
                    childCanvas = childCanvas.getContext("2d");
                    primaryCanvas.drawImage(childCanvas, 0, 0);
                });

            });
```

The issue here is when I get to the `childCanvas.getCo...` it tells me its undefined.

Suggestions or thoughts?

UPDATE:

Here is the example of the `div` layout I would be grabbing from:

```
<div class="ifp_container_printing ifp_container_printing_15" style="width:100%;" id="ifp_container_printing_15">
    <div class="kineticjs-content" role="presentation" style="position: relative; display: inline-block; width: 1665px; height: 1871px;">
      <canvas width="3330" height="3742" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1665px; height: 1871px; background: transparent;"></canvas>
      <canvas width="3330" height="3742" style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 1665px; height: 1871px; background: transparent;"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Plain `this` should work instead of `$(this).get()` - the `.get()` method returns an array.

Comment: @pointy that doesn't work.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Do you get an error? do you get anything? Also your code looks like it's trying to use "primaryCanvas" as a drawing context, but it's not - it's a jQuery wrapper around a `<canvas>` element.

Comment: can you post an example of the markup you're trying to traverse?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the wrong usage of `closest` method. It traverses up to the tree, check the [API](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

You may rewrite your code like this. This code will draw all canvases in a div on the first canvas in that div.

```
$(".ifp_container_printing").each(function() {
    var allCanvases = $(this).find('canvas');
    var primaryCanvas = allCanvases[0];
    var primaryContext = primaryCanvas.getContext('2d');

    for (var i = 1, len = allCanvases.length; i < len; i++) {
        // iterate through all canvases except the first
        primaryContext.drawImage(allCanvases[i], 0, 0);
    }
});
```